# How coroutine work with OnTriggerEnter2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, coroutine

I'm learning C# and unity, one of my recent issue is having my `OnTriggerEnter2D()` function work. After a lot of test i managed to resolve my issues but i'm not sure at 100% if i understood.

So basically i'm checking if an object touch another one and if this is not the case i rotate the object :

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            if (!door.connected)
            {
                go.transform.Rotate(0f, 0f, 90f, Space.Self);
            }
        }
```

This one didnt work and after a lot of debug i decided to use a coroutine with a 0.5s delay right after the `go.transform.Rotate(0f, 0f, 90f, Space.Self);` and this work.

If i'm right this work because the delay let enought time for my `OnTriggerEnter2D()` function to detect the collision or this have nothing to do with the `OnTriggerEnter2D()` ?  If this is the case, everytime i'm going to check for collision i'll need to use a coroutine ?

## Edit 1 : I have this code in another script

```
public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("Door"))
    {
        this.connected = true;
    }
}
```

So the previous loop will indeed make my object rotate but never set my public variable "connected" to true, like the collision never occur, except for the one spawning at the right spot. But when i use a coroutine it does work, why ?

Comment: You need to animate the rotation, not do four of them at the same time!

Comment: BTW for s simple delay, just use "Invoke" - don't worry about coroutines.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely don't need a coroutine to rotate an object in OnTriggerEnter2D.

It is currently instantly rotating the object 90 degrees 4 times (that's a full 360 degree rotation).  This happens inside a single frame, so the next time it renders it is still in exactly the same position.

The reason your code works when you add a coroutine is because the four 90 degree rotations don't all happen in a single frame then.  What happens is:

1. It rotates the door 90 degrees then kicks off a coroutine which last a few frames.
2. Since the door has changed rotation between frames, the other script gets the chance to detect any collisions
3. If it detects one with the door, it can set the `connected` flag to
   true which prevents `go.transform.Rotate` from being called in any subsequent
   frames.

Compare this to the sequence without the coroutine which would be:

1. It rotates the door 90 degrees, then it does it again, then again, then again... then it moves on to the next frame.
2. Since, as far as all other GameObjects are concerned, the door has
   NOT moved between frames no new collisions are detected and your
   `connected` flag remains false.

The solution to your problem isn't using a coroutine, though. The solution is to remove your `for` loop.  In the `Update` method, if the door is not connected rotate it a single degree step.  On the next update, if the door still isn't connected, do it again.  Eventually, within 4 updates, it will have become connected and it will no longer rotate every frame.

Answer (score 1):

> If i'm right this work because the delay let enought time for my OnTriggerEnter2D() function to detect the collision or this have nothing to do with the OnTriggerEnter2D() ?

No it has nothing to do with `OnTriggerEnter2D`. As you can see your collision is working and triggered.

What happens is that you rotate 4 times about 90° which sums up to 360° within one frame => You will note no difference.

---

A [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) in Unity is basically an [`IEnumerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator). Every [`IEnumerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator) at some point uses the [`yield`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield) keyword. So what a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) in Unity does is basically:

Each frame call `MoveNext` on the given `IEnumerator` until it either terminates or reaches the next `yield` statement. (There are some special cases like e.g. `WaitUntilEndOfFrame`...)

So translated you could say the `yield` means something like

- "Interrupt" this routine
- Render the current frame
- Continue the routine from here in the next frame

Btw. what you are doing via e.g.

```
yield return new WaitForseconds(3f);
```

basically equals doing something like

```
var timePassed = 0f;
while(timePassed < 3f)
{
    yield return null;
    timePassed += Time.deltaTime;
}
```

---

So: No for Collision detection you do **not** need to use a Coroutine; **BUT** whenever you want to "stretch" some codes execution over multiple frames you should use one.

What Unity does internally when you declare `OnTriggerEnter2D` as an `IEnumerator` basically equals something like

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    StartCoroutine(RotationAnimation());
}

private IEnumerator RotationAnimation()
{
    // ...
}
```

so you still have to be very careful that you don't get concurrent routines!

---

If what you want would actually be a smooth rotation you would e.g. use

```
private bool alreadyRotating;

// adjust this via the Inspector
[SerializeField] float rotationAnglePerSecond = 90f;

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    // avoid concurrent routines
    if(!alreadyRotating) StartCoroutine(RotationAnimation());
}

private IEnumerator RotationAnimation()
{
     // block concurrent routine
     if(alreadyRotating) yield break;
     alreadyRotating = true;

     var initialOrientation = go.transform.rotation;;

     // rotate until you reach 360°
     var rotated = 0f;
     while(rotated < 360f)
     {
         // get amount of rotation within this frame
         var rotate = Time.deltaTime * rotationAnglePerSecond;
         go.transform.Rotate(0f, 0f, 90f);           
         rotated += rotate;

         yield return null;
     }

     // reset to initial orientation
     go.transform.rotation = initialOrientation;    

     // when done allow the next routine
     alreadyRotating = false;
}
```